# fftw interface with complex.h in c

Tags: c, fftw, complex-numbers

I am using this code to create a 2D array having data type complex (from complex.h in c). Then I want to find the fft of that array 'in place'. However it is giving segmentation fault, which I fear is due to improper casting of the pointer. How do we use complex data type for a fftw?

```
//a is a 2d array of size blockSize*NO_INPUTS

complex float* a=(complex float*)malloc(sizeof(complex float)*NO_INPUTS*blockSize);

//****** Put data in a*******//
//blah//
//blah//

//a has data now//

fftw_plan p;
p=fftw_plan_dft_2d(blockSize,NO_INPUTS,(fftw_complex*)a,(fftw_complex*)a,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftw_execute(p);

fftw_destroy_plan(p);
```

Please note that I do not want to use fftw_complex or fftw_malloc.
Thank you.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used FFTW, but I seem to recall that fftw_complex defaults to complex if complex is defined.  Regarding fftw_malloc, why don't you want to use it?  These algorithms are highly dependent on the memory being byte-aligned.

Comment: In addition to good points from @Jim above, I think there are some additional constraints on the size of your 2D array for in-place 2D FFTs - you need some additional storage per row I believe (one extra elements ?) - there's a section in the FFTW manual on this.

Answer (score 3):

`fftw_complex` is equivalent to `complex double`, you are using `complex float`. That's probably the source of segfault.

Try including `complex.h` before `fftw3.h` you won't need to do any casts.

http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html

Answer (score 1):

FFTW defaults to using double precision floats by default. The simplest fix is just to change all instances of `float` to `double`.  If, however, you want to continue using `complex float` for memory or other reasons then you should use single precision fftw as outlined [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Precision.html#Precision). You should change lowercase `fftw` in all fftw function and type names to `fftwf`. For example `fftw_plan` becomes `fftwf_plan`. On compilation, you should link to `fftw3f` instead of `fftw3`.